# jQuery or jscript to hide and show SharePoint Ribbon bar

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a jQuery or javascript script that will allow end-users to hide or show the SharePoint Ribbon bar.  Basically giving them more room to work in.  Suggestions?

Comment: f1 in the sharepoint................

Answer (score 0):

You could add a floating div for this function, attaching "display:none" style to one of the elements below (as needed):

#s4-ribbonrow, #s4-titlerow, #s4-leftpanel